# HowTo Disable Thunderbird Unread Message Count Icons

Tags: icons, thunderbird

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and after a recent Thunderbird upgrade to version 115.3 I am now seeing small round icons with a count of unread messages next to each message folder. See image below:

[image: Image of round number Icons]

I want to disable this "feature" because I find it annoying. I haven't found anything in the Thunderbird settings that affects this behavior.

Note: This has nothing to do with the "Folder Pane Options" and the "Show Total Message Count" option.

Where is the setting to disable this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is a feature to disable that in Thunderbird.  If it is it's deep in the Thunderbird internals, and at the worst it's hardcoded and you'd have to recode Thunderbird.